# Can I use React and/or JSX as a templating language on the backend for any file extensions?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, backend, server-side-rendering, templating-engine

Let's say on my backend I have files with arbitrary extension `.ext` that I want to preprocess with a templating language. Can React and/or JSX be that language? For example:

```
// file foo.ext:
whatever
<insert-bar-here>

// file bar.ext:
blah blah blah
```

And I want to compile those files into a single one:

```
// compiled.ext
whatever
blah blah blah
```

Note, that it is not for frontend, it's not HTML. It's meant to give some organization and structure to backend files (and also solve some problems that are out of scope of this question).

I made a brief search but all results are about SSR, i.e. rendering html files for frontend, which is not my case.

I am asking because I have little experience in react and I don't want to invest significant amount of time into learning it, just to find out it's impossible.

Comment: Hi yes, I believe you can use JSX standalone, with a tool like [jsx-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-parser)

Comment: @IronMan thanks! Seems not so actively maintained and not very mature, though. I hope there's some more solid alternatives...

Comment: There is an implementation for Express.js for using React as a HTML view engine. While it is specifically not what you're looking for, it may be useful to see how they're doing it to see if you could just use that part: https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views